# Contiki TSCH queue add error

Tags: contiki

I'm developing a forwarding protocol using Contiki OS. The protocol is running on top of IEEE802.15.4 TSCH mode. The protocol requires to add a certain amount of packets during a short period of time very often I get following error:

```
[RLL]:Send to Parent 0 base timeslot: 40, currentTimeslot: 1, send timeslot: 45 at: asn-0.46c41d
TSCH: send packet to 255 with seqno 0, queue 0 1, len 8 120
[RLL]:Send to CS base timeslot: 40, currentTimeslot: 2, send timeslot: 50 at: asn-0.46c41e
TSCH-queue:! add packet failed: 0 #0x20003004 8 #0x0 #0x0
TSCH:! can't send packet to 255 with seqno 0, queue 1 1
```

While it adds the first packet, it can't add the second packet. The queue is not full, i checked that.
The error simply says, its not possible to allocate memory for another packet, while there should be more than enough space.

Probably its just a simple setting i oversea but I can't find it.
If anyone has a suggestion, please let me know.

Conrad